# Parallelism with the functions of OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I activate parallelism with OpenCV?

Is it possible to use parallelism for a single function?

```
void subtractBackground(Mat& frame, Mat& fgMask) {
    auto learningRate = (frameOk) ? 0 : -1;
    learningRate = (updateBg) ? 1 : learningRate;
    bgSubtractor.get()->apply(frame, fgMask, learningRate);

    if (!frameOk || updateBg) {
        bgSubtractor.get()->getBackgroundImage(bg);
        updateBg = false;
    }
}
```

This method slows down the performance of my system a lot, i want to parallelize it.

Comment: Have you tried function cv::setNumThreads (int nthreads) ? Accordingly to documentation, after set num of threads >0, OpenCV will try to set the number of threads for the next parallel region

Comment: Yes i tried but it not changed

Comment: read the source of the algorithm. has it been parallelized, or not?

Comment: @Laci i don't have any flag

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no :(